# PHP, PDO SQL query between two times then split per hour

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out if it is possible to query between 2 hours and parse per hour EG

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `production` WHERE `area` = '1' AND `datetime` BETWEEN '2016-10-21 08:00:00' AND "2016-10-21 10:00:00"
```

Result = 57

If it is possible i would like the output like this:

> 08:00 - 09:00 - 30
>  09:00 - 10:00 - 27

I am using PDO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found This Can Be Done At The SQL Level

```
SELECT HOUR(datetime), COUNT(*) FROM production
WHERE `area` = '1' AND `datetime` BETWEEN '2016-10-21 08:00:00' AND "2016-10-21 10:00:00"
GROUP BY HOUR(datetime)
```

This Returns

HOUR(datetime) - COUNT(*)
8 - 30
9 - 27
10 - 21

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do or how that query generates that result

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 GROUP BY HOUR(datetime)
```

Comment: thanks i also found this is the best way to compete this